# For any $N \in \mathbb{N}$ there exist integers $x,y,z>N$ such that $\{\sqrt{x}\}+\{\sqrt{y}\}=1+\{\sqrt{z}\}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

This problem is from the 2017 admission exam of the [SNS](https://www.sns.it/it) (see also page 142 of [this](https://www.sns.it/sites/default/files/2021-04/2%20010%202019%20provescienze%201%20anno.pdf) pdf for the original text in Italian)

The translation of the exercise is, more or less:

---

1. Given $N$ positive integer show that there exists integers $x,y,z>N$  such that
   $$
   \{\sqrt{x}\}+\{\sqrt{y}\}=1+\{\sqrt{z}\}
   $$
   where $\{a\}=a-\lfloor a \rfloor$ is the fractional part of the real number $a$
2. Show that for any three numbers of this kind $z>4N$

---

We can easily obtain that
$$
\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{z}=1+\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor+\lfloor \sqrt{y}\rfloor-\lfloor \sqrt{z}\rfloor
$$
Using the hint in the second part of the exercise i thought I can prove that, for any $N$ there is a squarefree integer $k>N$ such that
$$
\sqrt{k} \ge \lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor+\frac{1}{2}
$$
If this is true, by imposing $x=y=k$ and $z=4k$ we have a solution. I could not prove that  that there are square free numbers that satisfies such relation and I cannot prove that the condition $z>4N$ is actually necessary.

By looking to the set of solution with Python (with $N<100$) i have seen that these are not the only solution. *e.g* $$(8, 8, 32) \quad
(11, 99, 176) \quad (20, 245, 405)$$
are all solutions. Is my approach of focusing on squarefree numbers wrong? What would be a characterization of the triplets of solutions?

Comment: 1/ I do not see any strong reason to only focus on square free integers. Can you elaborate on why? 2/ Basically you couldn't make your wishful thinking work out. If so, either you need to push through, or edit your assumptions of "imposing $ x = y = k$ ... we have a solution" (like removing the square free condition, etc)

Comment: Possible ideas: Show that none of the fractional parts can equal zero. Then in all of the solutions generated by your program, write square root of each variable in the form of $m\sqrt n$. For ex. $(2\sqrt2,2\sqrt2,4\sqrt2), (\sqrt{11}, 3\sqrt{11}, 4\sqrt{11})$? why are they in this form (what can you say about fractional parts of square roots of numbers whose squarefree parts unequal?)

Comment: @CalvinLin was a starting point. I didn't though about the (rather straighforward) fact that the solutions of $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}=0$ are all of the form $(a^2k, b^2k, (a+b)^2k)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is satisfied iff

1. $ \sqrt{ x} + \sqrt{y} - \sqrt{z}  \in \mathbb{N}$
2. $\{\sqrt{x}\} + \{\sqrt{y} \} > 1 $

(Prove that this is the complete classification.)

OP's wishful thinking approach of $ x = y = k, z = 4k$ essentially gives us $ \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} - \sqrt{z} = 0 $, so condition 1 is satisfied.

To satisfy condition 2, we require $ \{ \sqrt{x} \} > 0.5$, which is true iff $ x \in [k^2 + k + 1 , k^2 + 2k ] $ for some positive integer $k$.
EG $ x = 3, 7, 8, \ldots$ are solutions, which could have been easily checked by OP.

---

A classification of all such triplets will take a bit more work.

All solutions to $ \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} - \sqrt{z} = 0 $ are of the form $(x, y, z) = (a^2k,b^2k, c^2k)$ where $ a+b = c$. EG The solutions that OP listed out at the end.
It remains to check when $\{\sqrt{x}\} + \{\sqrt{y} \} > 1 $, which to me doesn't seem to have a simple classification. We could do things like separately require $ \{x \}, \{y \} > 0.5$, but it doesn't cover all cases.

Comment: +1, but $x=6$ is not a solution